# find non-numeric values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say I import a csv into pandas, and I realize there are some non-numeric values in a column that I expect to be all numeric.

This is how I would find those values (in a dataframe called `df` in a column called `should_be_numbers`):

```py
df[pd.to_numeric(df['should_be_numbers'], errors='coerce').isnull()]['should_be_numbers']
```

My question:
Is there a cleaner/more pythonic/less clunky way to do this?

Comment: `pd.read_csv` has a `dtype` arg where you can specify the data type of the column. I'm assuming you have a column being stored as a string and you're getting scientific notation values

Comment: nope in this case its floats where the null values are all something like "-.--", but I don't know the data well enough to assume all the null values are filled in like that, and I don't want to blindly coerce in case its some weird formatting on valid data!

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'should_be_numbers': [1, 22, 'A', 'BB', [1, 22], ['A', 'BB'], 'A1BB22', np.nan, 3.13]})
df[[not (isinstance(value, int) or isinstance(value, float)) for value in df.should_be_numbers]]
```

Input:

```
  should_be_numbers
0                 1
1                22
2                 A
3                BB
4           [1, 22]
5           [A, BB]
6            A1BB22
7               NaN
8              3.13
```

Output:

```
  should_be_numbers
2                 A
3                BB
4           [1, 22]
5           [A, BB]
6            A1BB22
```